# Use of threading.Semaphore() in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to use semaphores in python and can't get them to work the way I want.

I have this code:

```
import os
import threading
import time

sem = threading.Semaphore(0)

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
  print("Blocking...", )
  sem.acquire()
  print("Pass!")
elif pid:
  time.sleep(2)  # Here goes code instead of sleep
  print("Releasing...")
  sem.release()
  print("Released")
```

And I expect it to print:

```
Blocking...
Releasing...
Released
Pass!
```

But it never prints out `Pass!` the semaphore gets stuck at the `sem.acquire()` even though I did a `sem.release()` and I can't figure out why, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Initial value of semaphore should be 1

Comment: if I put the initial value to 1 then it prints ```Blocking/Pass/Releasing/Released``` which isn't the order I want it

Comment: You're trying to use a thread synchronization primitive with `os.fork`, which doesn't make threads. `threading.Thread` makes threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import threading
import time

sem = threading.Semaphore() # default value is 1

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
  print("Blocking...", )
  sem.acquire()
  print("Pass!")
elif pid:
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Releasing...")
  sem.release()
  print("Released")
```

"Entering" to semaphore is a decrement of its value.

To get exact that sequence of the messages, you can use something like this:

```py
import os, sys
import threading
import time

sem = threading.Semaphore(1)

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
  print("Blocking...")
  sem.acquire()
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Pass!")
elif pid:
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Releasing...")
  sem.release()
  print("Released")
```

but right solution is to avoid hardcoded "timing" but to communicate with some Queue or Events.

Comment: If I do that it doesn't print it the order I want, because I want the acquire to lock the semaphore until I release it in the other proccess

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. After enter of semaphore you go immediately to `print("Pass!")` and this sub-process is exiting. Then another sub-process ends with sleeping and prints "Releasing..." and releases the semaphore. This is what happens. You can use event objects to tightly communication between processes

Comment: That's why I set the value of the semaphore to 0, so the first enter to the semaphore locks it until the other process releases it.I got it working that way in perl but I can't find a way to translate it to python

Comment: Then it cannot enter the semaphore. The initial value is the number of allowed concurrent inbox subprocesses.

Comment: I don't want it to enter the semaphore, I want it to lock it the first time I call acquire(). I tried with ```threading.Lock()``` and ```threading.Event()``` and all exhibit the same behaviour, I can't unlock them from other processes. I can't get it to print out ```Pass!``` the last one

Comment: If you have the initial value to 0 - you cannot enter, but if it's 1, then you enter (acquired it) and then immediately call print of "pass". You have not explicit synchronization between subprocesses. You can simulate it with `time.sleep()` but it's not correct. I will add to my answer how it can look (but it's wrong)